# NGRX error " Dispatch expected an object, instead it received a function. If you're using the createAction function ..."

Tags: angular, reactive-programming, ngrx

I followed a tutorial on Youtube and i tried to create my own project but i keep getting an error in the browserthat says Dispatch expected an Object.

my Modeles:

```
export interface Football {
  title: string;
  embed: string;
  date: string;
  url: string;
  thumbnail: string;
}
export interface State {
  footballs: Football[];
  isLoading: boolean;
  error: string;
}

export const initialState: State = {
  footballs: null,
  isLoading: false,
  error: '',
};
```

Actions:

```
export const loadAllSucceeded = createAction('[Football Api] Load All succeeded', props<{footballs: Football[]}>());

export const loadAllFailed = createAction('[Football Api] Load All succeeded', props<{error: string}>());

export const appComponentInitialized = createAction('[App Component] Initialized');

export const loadAllRequested = createAction('[App Component] Load All Requested');
```

Selectors:

```
export const selectFeature = (state: State) => state;

export const selectFootballList = createSelector(selectFeature, (state: State) => state.footballs);
export const selectFootballIsLoading = createSelector(selectFeature, (state: State) => state.isLoading || false);
export const selectFootballError = createSelector(selectFeature, (state: State) => state.error || '');
```

Effects:

```
@Injectable()
export class FootballStoreEffects {

  constructor(private footballService: FootballService, private actions$: Actions) {
  }

  loadAll = createEffect(() =>
    this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(FootballActions.loadAllRequested),
      switchMap(() =>
    this.footballService.getFootballVideos()
      .pipe(
      map(footballs => FootballActions.loadAllSucceeded({footballs})),
      catchError(error => of(FootballActions.loadAllFailed({error})))
    )))
  );
}
```

reducers:

```
const featureReducer = createReducer(
  initialState, on(FootballActions.loadAllRequested, state => ({...state, isLoading: true, error: ''})),
  on(FootballActions.loadAllSucceeded, (state, props) => ({... state, isLoading: false, error: '', footballs: props.footballs})),
  on(FootballActions.loadAllFailed, (state, {error}) => ({... state, isLoading: false, error}) )
);

export function reducer(state: State | undefined, action: Action) {
  return featureReducer(state, action);
}
```

Service Methode:

```
  getFootballVideos(): Observable<Football[]> {
    return this.http.get<FootballResult>(this.API_BASE_URL).pipe(map(result => result.value));
  }
```

Component :

```
export class FootballVideosComponent implements OnInit {

  footballs$: Observable<Football[]>;
  error$: Observable<string>;
  isLoading$: Observable<boolean>;

  constructor(private store: Store<State>) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.footballs$ = this.store.pipe(select(FootballSelectors.selectFootballList));
    this.error$ = this.store.pipe(select(FootballSelectors.selectFootballError));
    this.isLoading$ = this.store.pipe(select(FootballSelectors.selectFootballIsLoading));

  }

  onRefresh() {
    this.store.dispatch(FootballActions.loadAllRequested);
  }

}
```

I get this error in the browser when i execute onRefresh():

ERROR TypeError: 
                Dispatch expected an object, instead it received a function.
                If you're using the createAction function, make sure to invoke the function
                before dispatching the action. For example, someAction should be someAction().
            at ActionsSubject.next (store.js:159)
            at Store.dispatch (store.js:704)
            at FootballVideosComponent.onRefresh (football-videos.component.ts:29)
            at Object.eval [as handleEvent] (FootballVideosComponent.html:3)
            at handleEvent (core.js:43993)
            at callWithDebugContext (core.js:45632)
            at Object.debugHandleEvent [as handleEvent] (core.js:45247)
            at dispatchEvent (core.js:29804)
            at core.js:42925
            at HTMLButtonElement. (platform-browser.js:2668)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try to add `()` like this:

```
onRefresh() {
  this.store.dispatch(FootballActions.loadAllRequested());
}
```